# (1==1 | 2==1) is False?

Tags: python

Python returns if I do

```
>>> (1==1 | 2==1)
False
```

But

```
>>> (True | False)
True
```

Why?

Edit:

Yes `or` will solve the 'problem'. But I was asking why there is a difference between the two outputs above. The answer is that bitwise or has precedence, as @MartijnPieters, @Cong-Ma, @Yohboy explained in the comment.

In Pandas for example we are forced to use bitwise operators because python's standard logical operators don't work, so in those cases we should be careful to do

```
>>> ((1==1) | (2==1))
```

Comment: `|` is **bitwise or**, not logical or.

Comment: And it has a different precedence from `or`, so you calculated `1 == (1 | 2) == 1`, which is the same as `1 == (1 | 2) and (1 | 2) == 1`. `1 | 2` is 3, so `1 == 3 == 1` is false.

Comment: This is an [operator precedence problem](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: `1==1 or 2==1` gives True

Comment: Or add parenthesis : ((1==1) | (2==1))

Comment: research bitwise operators (he's not asking how to fix he's asking why the behaviour happens)

Comment: @MartijnPieters and Cong Ma Okay it's a precedence problem. Got it!

Comment: The bitwise pipe is not the or. 
The `or` is what you're looking for. :))

Answer (score 2):

The Python operator `|` is not a logical or. Try using

`(1==1 or 2==1)`

instead.

Answer (score -1):

| is not the logical or. 'or' is the keyword you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I understand but in this case both will work. The problem was of precedence. I use them with pandas where sometimes you cannot use `and`, `not`.

Comment: then specify it in question that you are using python with panda @user7867665